# Dump info from API into Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, model

I am making the transition from running Ruby scripts in my terminal to running them within a rails app. Within my ruby script I have this code:

```
call = "#{client_id}/lookup/member/email?email=#{email}"
url = HTTParty.get("#{base_uri}#{call}",
  :basic_auth => auth,
  :headers => {'Accept' => 'application/json' } )

response = JSON.parse(url.body)

email = response["email"]
```

This returns, for example, an `email`.

Then, in a separate project, I have a model in my Rails App called `Email`.

How can I take the above API call from my script to dynamically create "`Emails`" within my Rails app so that I can do something like this:

```
<% @emails.each do |email| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to email.id, email_path(email) %></td>
    <td><%= email.name %></td>
    <td><%= email.surveyid %></td>
    <td><%=l email.created_at %></td>
......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use a serialized / marshalled hash by using YAML.load / dump. Or you can go one by one and map api fields to an active record object.

```
e = Email.new
e.name = response["email"]["name"]
e.surveryid = response["email"]["surveyid"]
#........ Adittional field mappings ...........
e.save
```

Comment: This code makes sense to me - But where would that code live to be run in time for the view to populate the correct forms. My understanding of the different modules within Rails is very limited, which I think is the main issue I'm having. Perhaps some tips on where to learn how the different pieces of rails work together is more along the lines of what I need.

Comment: @Luigi If you're getting the data from a web service why do you need a form?